# Cannot burn Ubuntu ISO onto DVD in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, dvd-burning

I am running Windows 8 and I downloaded an Ubuntu 12.10 ISO onto my hard drive. When I right-click on the file and selected “Burn to disc”, I get the following message:

> The selected disc image file isn't valid.

Please advise on what to do. I am not using any third-party disc burning software since such a software is already built into Windows 8 by default.

Comment: have you compared md5 checksums?

Comment: What is the full filename (including extension)?

Comment: @Ramhound: "Windows 8 nor any version of Window has the built-in ability to burn ISO files." Win7+ includes [Windows Disc Image Burner](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-from-an-iso-file).

Answer (score 1):

If the image file you downloaded is ok I suggest you download [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) and use that to burn the image to disk. It is free and is probably the best there is at burning images to disk. There is a somewhat dated review at [PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/231530/imgburn.html) if you want to review it first.

You can automate the install if you use [Ninite](http://ninite.com/)

Comment: +1 for imgburn.  I switched to imgburn from Daemon Tools because I was having many issues with Daemon Tools burning ISOs correctly.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ  what are you talking about. You say you were "having many issues with Daemon Tools burning ISOs correctly." and you say you "switched to imgburn from Daemon Tools". Maybe you mean you had issues with windows burning

Answer (score 0):

if you have a flash drive that is 4gb or larger you can give unetbootin a go. It's my companies preferred method for installing any OS now, and it is a lot faster than from a disk. It may help you out as they have a built in "download and setup ubuntu" option.

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

if you are on linux already there might be a package in your repo for it already, so check there first.

Answer (score 0):

I use [WinISO](http://www.winiso.com), 
In my view, it's easy for me to burn and make ISO files. 
It's not free, but if you'd like, you can have a try. It support for free download, the only limitation of WinISO is the saving size. Download here:http://download.cnet.com/WinISO/3000-2646_4-10062544.html.

Answer (score 0):

Use [poweriso](http://www.poweriso.com/download.htm) to burn image file, check whether your downloaded file is not broken.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that windows disc image burner will not accept an iso which has an actual file size that is not a multiple of 2kb.

Most other software will burn it, but if you want windows to do it, you need to add some padding to the file.

Comment: Welcome.  The original post was from 1 1/2 years ago.  Are you familiar the that iso or know for sure that it is not a multiple of 2k and that that is the problem?  Also, most people don't know how to pad an iso.  For that recommendation to be useful, could you briefly explain how to accomplish it?